# Deleting a set of columns after selection of a defined value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

In a sheet, I have a table of sheets/columns where the user should select **YES/NO** depending on which columns to keep/remove from which sheet.
When the user selects **YES** nothing should happen as the columns already exist, but if he selects **NO** the columns of the other sheets must be removed.

Until now I did this code, but nothing changes :

Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Const TEMPLATE_SHE As String = "TemplateSHE"

```
Sub GenerateSHE()

Dim ws, wsh As Worksheet, Cel1 As Range
Dim Var1 As String
Dim Col_num As Integer
Dim Col_name As String
Dim MyRange As Range

 Set ws = Worksheets(4)
            For Each Cel1 In ws.UsedRange
               If (Cel1.Value = "NO") Then
                   For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                          With wsh.Name <> TEMPLATE_SHE
                                Col_num = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
                                Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, Col_num)).Cells.Find(Col_name)
                                If Left(MyRange, 3) = "LEW" Then
                                    Columns("AY:BC").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                                    ElseIf Left(MyRange, 3) = "RMS" Then
                                    Columns("AT:AX").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                                    ElseIf Left(MyRange, 3) = "AMS" Then
                                    Columns("AR:AS").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                                    ElseIf Left(MyRange, 2) = "MM" Then
                                    Columns("AM:AQ").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                                    ElseIf Left(MyRange, 2) = "QM" Then
                                    Columns("AH:AL").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                                    ElseIf Left(MyRange, 3) = "TEM" Then
                                    Columns("AC:AG").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                                    ElseIf Left(MyRange, 3) = "LMM" Then
                                    Columns("X:AB").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                                End If
                        End With
                   Next wsh
               End If
            Next
        Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me correct my code?

Comment: Is the `NO` button linked properly with the sub/macro?

Comment: Actually its an activeX combobox not a button.. is the Cel1.Value not really working? how can i link it to the macro?

Comment: Can you post your complete sub/macro? This way I can verify if the trigger is properly made.

Comment: Is there a way to send you a proper example of the excel file so you can have an idea about my request?

Comment: I added the full code, can you please check it?

Comment: I found the solution, should anyone look for the solution just ask me :)

Comment: Oh! I was trying to figure it out just now. What was the problem? (Out of curiosity)

Comment: You should write your solution as an answer below, so that if someones has the same problem as you, he can use your solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that works for me, it's completely different from what i have started with:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, [B2:E5]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Value = "YES" Then Exit Sub
  Call Del_Colns(Target.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, _
                         Target.EntireColumn.Cells(1, 1).Value)
End Sub

Private Sub Del_Colns(sheeet As String, colns As String)
Dim i As Long

  With Worksheets(sheeet).UsedRange.Rows(1)
    For i = .Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
      If InStr(1, .Cells(1, i).Formula, colns) = 1 Then
        .Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
      End If
    Next i
  End With

End Sub
```